# Trouble with Images in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, security, ssl, https

I have a Magento site (CE 1.9.0.1) with images in the footer. I'm having trouble getting these images to display correctly on the checkout page. Sometimes when I view the page they are displaying correctly and we have a "padlock". Other times the images appear broken and browsers show our checkout as unsafe.

I've looked up this issue, and found that you can refer to the image source without using an http or https protocol. I've taken the protocol out and still off and on results.

Is there something I'm missing, or a better way to do this?

The site in question is [here](http://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/). I appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you add some more information about the browsers which show your checkout as unsafe? There are differences on the types and certificate details (such as algorithms, key length,...) that are accepted by various browsers. So the integration of accepted certificates is different.

Implementing the images without a protocoll (or with https only) should be fine.

Comment: Anna, thanks for the comment. I am primarily testing in Chrome and Firefox. Both will sometimes show the images fine with no security warnings and sometimes the images are broken with a browser warning. So the issue doesn't seem to be dependent on browser type.

Comment: Hi Amanda, any news on this? Did you resolve it meanwhile?

Comment: Hi Anna - Thanks for checking back in. I finally just added the https protocol to all the images affected. It wasn't my ideal option, but they seem to be loading fine now. I appreciate your help!